# TabActivity not resuming

Tags: android

I'm developing an application where in i create a database under a class which extends tab activity. but when my tab activity resumes , my application crashes. any help would be appreciated.

**Here is my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static   boolean paid=false;
    public String num;
    public String num1;
    public String  name;
    static int delay;
    public static Boolean fromapp=false;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    TabHost tabHost;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(fromapp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

      /*  
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DialPad.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("DIAL PAD").setIndicator("DIAL PAD",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);*/


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Calllog.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("CALL LOG").setIndicator("CALL LOG",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Contacts.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("CONTACTS").setIndicator("CONTACTS",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fromapp(delay INTEGER);");

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from Fromapp", null);


        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
        }
        else
        {
            db.execSQL("insert into Fromapp values("+5000+")");
        }



 }





    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
     {

            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.ten:
                db.execSQL("update Fromapp set delay="+10000);


                return true;
            case R.id.twenty:
                db.execSQL("update Fromapp set delay="+20000);


                return true;
            case R.id.fifty:
                db.execSQL("update Fromapp set delay="+30000);


                return true;    
            case R.id.hundred:
                db.execSQL("update Fromapp set delay="+40000);
                return true;
            case R.id.twohundred:
                db.execSQL("update Fromapp set delay="+50000);
                return true;
            case R.id.fivehundred:
                db.execSQL("update Fromapp set delay="+60000);
                return true;    

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();       
    }
```

**My LogCat shows the below**

```
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.thoughtrix.tryamisscall/com.thoughtrix.tryamisscall.MainActivity}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547): Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:64)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5148)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performRestartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3214)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:168)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchResume(LocalActivityManager.java:523)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.ActivityGroup.onResume(ActivityGroup.java:61)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at com.thoughtrix.tryamisscall.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:134)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
11-01 12:28:49.513: E/AndroidRuntime(32547):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer ultimately. This exception used to pop up because of the "managedQuery" in my calllog class. I used to explicitly close the cursor after retrieving data using managedQuery. This must not be done. Your Activity will automatically close the cursor for you when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your database

```
db.getWritableDatabase();
db.open();
```